# ViewPager starting from the right

Tags: android, android-viewpager

i am developing an arabic android application and i have the compatibility package referenced

i have a ViewPager that displays my content but i want to start scrolling the pager view from the right 
making the starting page on the far right of the pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don`t think it is easy to do, maybe using [java reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/)

Another and easier solution is to use your last page like your first page. So at the start you just call:

```
YourViewPager.setCurrentItem(YourViewPagerSize);
```

Comment: let me try that and reverse my arays